# monotouch rotate and navigationViewController

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, xamarin.ios, rotation

I'm new in monotouch and I'm having a problem using NavigationViewController:
In the FinishedLauching method, if I comment this line:

window.AddSubview(viewController.NavigationController.View);

The window rotates with no problem but the navigationController doesn't work.
If this line is in code(not comment) the navigationController works but the screen doesn't rotates.

Anyone knows how solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the RootViewController property of the UIWindow is the proper way to use the Navigation Controller.

```cs
MyViewCtrl ctrl1 = new MyViewCtrl ("One");
_nav = new UINavigationController (ctrl1);

window.RootViewController = _nav;
```

Also don't forget to override the ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method in your controller.  Here is a full sample

```cs
[Register ("AppDelegate")]
public partial class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
{
    UIWindow window;
    UINavigationController _nav;

    public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

        MyViewCtrl ctrl1 = new MyViewCtrl ("One");
        _nav = new UINavigationController (ctrl1);

        window.RootViewController = _nav;
        window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();

        return true;
    }
}

public class MyViewCtrl : UIViewController
{
    public MyViewCtrl (string title)
    {
        this.Title = title;
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();
        this.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;

        if (this.Title.Equals ("One"))
        {
            UIBarButtonItem testButton = 
                new UIBarButtonItem ("Two", UIBarButtonItemStyle.Bordered, 
                                     (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
                    this.NavigationController.PushViewController (
                        new MyViewCtrl ("Two"), true);
                } );
            this.NavigationItem.RightBarButtonItem = testButton;    
        }
    }   

    public override bool ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation (UIInterfaceOrientation toInterfaceOrientation)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```